# Update values in a column not working - Dplyr

Tags: r

I'm looking to update a column that has age values of '95+' so that each occurrence of that value is changed to '95' instead. It is a CHR column. Should the below not work? It does not seem to cause any update to the data.

```
PopulationData <- PopulationData %>%
  mutate(AGE =str_replace(AGE, "95+", "95"))
```

Comment: Can you pout some of the data set in as a minimum reproducible example please?

Comment: use `str_replace(AGE, "95\\+", "95"))` the + is looking for more 5's

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phiver's below response for solving. The '+' was throwing an issue - below works:

```
PopulationData <- PopulationData %>%
  mutate(AGE =str_replace(AGE, "95\\+", "95"))
```